# Performance diference between absolute and relative Url in an Ajax interal Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

So far you can do this by 2 ways; with relative and absolute urls:

**absolute in the same server:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.host.net/customers'
})
```

**or directly by relative url in the same server:**

> $.ajax({
>       url: '/customers' })

Despite the diference showed here, in jQuery is there any performance diference by using any of them?

Comment: You should specify what the absolute vs relative urls are doing, if they do the exact same thing there is no difference. But if your talking about hitting an external api vs hitting a script that access that api on your own server, then performance should be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make any difference at all. jQuery will pass it on to xhr as-is without modification. Whether or not it makes a difference once it reaches the xhr method will depend on browser implementation, however, it's unlikely to account for more than 0.00ms.

Comment: Of course, if the endpoints are different, network speed and server speed will come into play. (external server vs internal server)